# How to use Java ICAP codec with Squid

Tags: java, squid

I am trying use [Java ICAP Codec](http://icap.mimo.ch/) 1.0.0.GA Squid Echo example with Squid and got the following exception

```
ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapDecodingError: Mandatory ICAP message header [Encapsulated] is missing
    at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.ReadIcapHeaderState.validateMandatoryMessageHeaders(ReadIcapHeaderState.java:104)
    at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.ReadIcapHeaderState.execute(ReadIcapHeaderState.java:54)
    at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapMessageDecoder.decode(IcapMessageDecoder.java:97)
    at ch.mimo.netty.handler.codec.icap.IcapMessageDecoder.decode(IcapMessageDecoder.java:37)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:470)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
```

Here is my Squid config (related to ICAP):

```
icap_enable on
icap_service service_req reqmod_precache icap://127.0.0.1:1344
adaptation_access service_req allow all
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Squid's ICAP client is known not to add an Encapsulated Header to Options requests. The latest 1.0.0.GA release of the [Java ICAP Codec](http://icap.mimo.ch) will handle Options, and 100 Continue requests  with missing Encapsulated headers.

I suggest you dump the network traffic with Wireshark and post it here.